# How can I tell bash top stop echoing text whenever I press any key?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, keyboard, shell

I'm writing a custom startup command for gnome-terminal, and my intention is to display a welcome message every time I launch it.

The message displays correctly, I coded it in order to make the letters appear one by one in a time rate of 0.09s:

```
echo -n "W" 
sleep 0.09
echo -n "e" 
sleep 0.09
echo -n "l"
sleep 0.09
echo -n "c"
sleep 0.09
echo -n "o"
sleep 0.09 
echo -n "m"
sleep 0.09 
echo -n "e" 
sleep 0.09
```

While testing it, I thought it would be quite comfortable to be able to stop the letters from appearing and start `su` directly. I came up with the following solution:

```
su --command "read -n 1 -s key; if [[ "$key" == "g" ]]; then echo "Test Successful."; else echo "Test Failed."; fi;"
```

I have to use `su -c` if I don't want bash to get angry and throw an `illegal action: read -n`. This code snippet is for debugging purposes exclusively, as I wanted to test how does bash read the one-line command combination.

The main problem comes when I try to execute this code from the config file (the one where I write my custom command for startup). Bash returns:

```
No passwd entry for user 'Successful.; else echo Test'
Welcome
```

Mysteriously, when I try the same command (without `su -c` ) in the default profile it works perfectly, but if I try it with su -c, it doesn't.

Trying with other commands in the default profile, I typed `su -c "echo Hi"` and worked fine. Why could be this happening? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the whole command in single quotes instead of double.
First thing to note is you have a variable ($key). Enclosed in double quotes, it will be substituted by the shell before making it an argument given to `su`.
Second thing is regarding quote matching what you currently have, with double quotes, the argument will be split like this:

- arg0: `su`
- arg1: `--command`
- arg2: `read -n 1 -s key; if [ <value of $key or nothing> == g ]; then echo Test`
- arg3: `Successful.; else echo Test`
- arg4: `Failed.; fi;`

Enclosing the whole args in single quotes allows fixes the two issues, avoid variable substitution and fixes the split weirdness, by passing this string as-is as the second argument of `su`.

Bonus: as a general note, avoid double brackets for tests when possible, it's a bashism (syntax that only work with bash and could be replaced by a more compatible counter part)

The following version should work as expected.

```
su --command 'read -n 1 -s key; if [ "$key" == "g" ]; then echo "Test Successful."; else echo "Test Failed."; fi;'
```

Comment: Alright, it works. Thank you so much! But now I need the function to work while the 'echoes' work, like if it was executing in background. Any clue?

Comment: You can background the commands that echoes by surrounding them with parentheses and putting it in back ground with a &. This might messup the display if you write during it ;) ex: (echo foo; sleep 1; echo bar)&

Comment: And how should I do if I want the read command work at the same time as the echoes, and stop them if I press any key? I've tried with your answer, but it's not giving me the proper results. What I would like is to turn "echo: "Test..." into a su command that stop echoes and starts a command line, but I get: "bash: cannot set terminal process group (3700): Inappropriate ioctl for device". The command itself is: "(su --command 'read -n 1 -s key; if [ "$key" == "g" ]; then su; fi;') &"